# Specifying link load location using Anchors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple link which reloads the current page. This is shown below:

```
echo '<a href="#" id ="mybutton"></a>';
```

When I click on the link it takes me to the top of the page.

**How can I modify it to take me back where the link is located please?**

**I would also like to give it an offset so the location would not be all the way at the top but there would be a little bit of padding**

Comment: How would a link take you *back* to the link itself? You can trivially make a link point to itself, but that would not mean going back. What’s the purpose here? You want to go up in the document, just place an anchor somewhere before the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the `<a>` tag a `name` field? Then modify the `href` to direct back to it - i.e.:

`<a name="thisPosition" href="#thisPosition" id="mybutton">...</a>;`

EDIT: To reflect the comments, here is an addendum - the 'name' field is not strictly required, most (if not all) browsers nowadays can simply identify an 'id' attribute, so the href could be modified thusly: `href="#mybutton"`, forgoing the 'name' attribute.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor <- here's a live example too

Comment: Yeah, actually, you don't need to bother with the 'name', just change the href to move back to the 'id' value: `<a href="#mybutton" id="mybutton">`

Comment: that will not reload the page. so the server will not send you any updated data

Comment: one more thing, can I specify an offset(maybe using javascript).. Its too up for my liking

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, it is not possible to specify an offset. Could you perhaps move the anchor a bit further up? ;)

Comment: I tried to create an invisible link <a id = in><\a> and adding a few <br>s before my button, but its not working

Comment: Still wouldnt work with the quotes. I managed to solve this by adding text to the link (apparently it required text) and then hidding it with css.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use this Javascript, which will refresh the page, just like hitting F5 or clicking the refresh button. The browser will remember the position.

```
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Refresh</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an offset to the position so that the item I want to go back to won't be at the top completely?

Comment: if you use javascript:location.reload() the browser will scroll you back to the same scoll position you were at before the link was clicked